Do the monotone maps from a poset into a Heyting algebra form a Heyting algebra?
I am interested in generalizing the fact that the up-sets of a poset always form a Heyting algebra.
Let $P$ be a poset and $H$ a Heyting algebra. $\operatorname{Hom}(P,H)$ can be made a bound lattice using pointwise operations, so that just leaves implication.
I know that if $H$ is complete, we can define implication as a join:
$$ (f \rightarrow g)(x) := \bigvee \lbrace h(x) | h \in \operatorname{Hom}(P,H), h \wedge f \leq g \rbrace. $$
I am curious if the assumption of completeness is necessary.

You can prove that $(f\to g)(x) = f(x)\to g(x)$. You might need some equational axioms of Heyting algebra.

@amrsa But isn't $f(x) \rightarrow g(x)$ not monotone in general?

I think you are correct: if $x\leq y$ and $f(x)\leq g(x)$ but $f(y)\nleq g(y)$, then $f(x)\to g(x)=1$ but $f(y)\to g(y)<1$. And it's not difficult to come up with one such example! I'll leave the comment, nevertheless, in case someone else has the same idea.

Ok, now you have an answer, which seems to me to be correct and I upvoted it, so soon I might come back and delete my comments. All the best!

If $H$ is complete, you can also write $(f\rightarrow g)(x) := \bigwedge { f(y) \rightarrow g(y) \mid y \ge x }$.  (This would be a straightforward generalization of the fact that in the up-sets of a poset, the relative pseudocomplement is $S \rightarrow T := { x \mid \forall y \ge x, y \in S \rightarrow y \in T }$.)

I would be interested to hear more about this construction, and your motivation for studying it. However, I believe that in general it should not yield a Heyting algebra. Here is my counterexample idea.
Consider $\omega+1$, the one point compactification of the natural numbers; the dual Boolean algebra of this is the (not complete) finite and cofinite collection of the naturals. Let $H$ be such an algebra. Let $P=\mathbb{N}$ be the natural numbers with their natural order. Let $f$ be the function which enumerates the finite subsets of the \textit{even} numbers, as $f(n)=[0,n]\cap Even$. This is of course a monotone function. Let $\overline{0}$ be the constant function at the empty set. Assume that $h=f\rightarrow 0$ existed. Then by definition of the relative pseudocomplement, we would have $$a\wedge f=0 \iff a\leq h$$
for any $a\in Hom(\mathbb{N},P)$. Now, let $o_{k}$ be a function defined by letting $o_{k}(0)=\{1,3,...,k\}$, where $k$ is some odd number, and then an enumeration of the odds from then on. Then $o_{k}(m)\cap f(m)=\emptyset$, obviously, so $o_{k}\wedge f=\overline{0}$. Hence $o_{k}\leq h$, so in particular $o_{k}(0)\leq h(0)$. Since $o_{k}$ can be made arbitrarily big, and $o_{k}(0)\subseteq h(0)$, then $h(0)$ must be cofinite. But then by monotonicity, this means that $h$ must be eventually constant at a cofinite set. Since $f$ grows arbitrarily large, there must then be some $k$ such that $f(k)\wedge h(k)\neq \emptyset$, which is absurd.

Good (+1), but why do you call $o_k$ to a function that doesn't depend on $k$? I guess it actually does, and the idea would be to make $$o_k(0)={1,3,5,\ldots,k},$$ for odd $k$, then $$o_k(1)=o_k(0)\cup{k+2}$$ and so on? I think that would make sense.

You are absolutely right, I edited the answer to reflect this!

Nice proof, thanks! The question wasn't really motivated by anything other than curiosity about how weak I could make my assumptions.  I am working on a formal proof where it is easier to think of up-sets as monotone functions, which led me to structuring things as above.
